# Error when trying to run or build Flutter project for iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So basically I can run other projects and I can run this one for Android but when I want to run it or build it for iOS I get the following error message. Also it's not project related issue, my co-worker can run it just fine. I tried every possible online solution, adding post install stuff to Podfile, tried changing to 'legacy build system' in Xcode but same error, tried reinstalling Pod, CocoaPods, even switched to beta. No idea what to do anymore.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
 
Running pod install...                                             23.5s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           28.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-5.0.1+1/ios/Classes/strategies/PhotoPermissionStrategy.m:39:13:
    warning: enumeration value 'PHAuthorizationStatusLimited' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
        switch (authorizationStatus) {
                ^
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-5.0.1+1/ios/Classes/strategies/PhotoPermissionStrategy.m:39:13:
    note: add missing switch cases
        switch (authorizationStatus) {
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_downloader-0.19.2/ios/Classes/SwiftImageDownloaderPlugin.swift:37:17: error:
    switch must be exhaustive
                    switch status {
                    ^
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_downloader-0.19.2/ios/Classes/SwiftImageDownloaderPlugin.swift:37:17: note: do
    you want to add missing cases?
                    switch status {
                    ^
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.2.0/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:45:52:
    warning: assigning to 'id<IAPPromotionObserverDelegate>' from incompatible type 'FlutterInappPurchasePlugin *__strong'
        [IAPPromotionObserver sharedObserver].delegate = self;
                                                       ^ ~~~~
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.2.0/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:200:79:
    warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'SKPaymentTransactionState' (aka 'enum SKPaymentTransactionState') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                                         [NSNumber numberWithInt: item.transactionState], @"transactionStateIOS",
                                                         ~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/djordje/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inapp_purchase-2.2.0/ios/Classes/FlutterInappPurchasePlugin.m:586:71:
    warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'SKPaymentTransactionState' (aka 'enum SKPaymentTransactionState') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: transaction.transactionState], @"transactionStateIOS",
                                                 ~                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'image_downloader' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Protobuf' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseDynamicLinks' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FBSDKLoginKit' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'scrollable_bottom_sheet' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'permission_handler' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'map_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'location_permissions' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'location' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'maps_launcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'google_sign_in' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'google_maps_flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'geolocator' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'geocoder' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'flutter_inapp_purchase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'flutter_email_sender' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'flutter_appavailability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_dynamic_links' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'device_info' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'contacts_service' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'apple_sign_in' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to
    14.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: fixed mine by installing the latest version of cocoapods then `pod install`, throw in a bit of `flutter clean` as well

Answer (score 1):

Related to [Flutter project - XCode build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058133/flutter-project-xcode-build-failed)

First, verify that you are in flutter channel stable, and flutter upgrade

Then, what worked for me :

```sh
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods; 
sudo gem install cocoapods; 
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios; pod install; cd ..;
```

Other commands that might help

```
cd ios; pod install --repo-update; cd ..;
//deactivate rvm
rvm use system
```

Other ideas :

- Delete the entire repo and git clone
- Delete Derived Data (check Google)
- Delete Podspec.lock and Gemfile.lock