# Unable to run xCode task in DevOps

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I editted the yaml to reflect comments below.

I am getting the following error when I try to run my Pipeline and get to running the xCode task:

**The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')**

My Pipeline yaml file looks like this....

```
variables:
  scheme: "App"
  sdk: "iphoneos"
  configuration: "Release"

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.15' #'macOS-latest'


- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'Certificates.p12'
    certPwd: 'mypassword'
    keychain: 'temp'
    deleteCert: true

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles' 
    provProfileSecureFile: Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision
    removeProfile: true

- script: |
    sudo gem install cocoapods
  displayName: 'Install Cocoa Pods'

- script: |
    pod repo update
  displayName: 'Update Cocoa Pods'

- script: |
    ionic cordova build ios --prod --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
  displayName: 'Build Ionic iOS App'

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'MyProject'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios/TechPro.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    teamId: 'myteamid'
    exportTeamId: 'myteamid'
    exportMethod: 'ad-hoc'
    exportOptions: 'specify'
    exportOptionsPlist: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/platforms/ios/MyProject/MyProject-Info.plist'
```

I modified the podfile to add the following...

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
            config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An Xcode app must be signed and provisioned to run on a device or be published to the App Store. It looks like your ios app is not successfully signed.

This arguement `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No` will skip the code signing. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034133/building-ios-applications-using-xcodebuild-without-codesign). You can also check the task log of the Xcode task to see if your app is successfully signed.

You could try to remove the arguments `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No -CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO` in Xcode task and check if it could work.

Comment: If I do that, then I get this error.... The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')

Comment: Hi @Adam. Please refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058133/flutter-project-xcode-build-failed You may need to change the settings in your project

Comment: I am not using flutter and we haven't in the past, so there is no flutter directory.